# C++ incomplete output when splitting string

Tags: c++, string, vector, split

im trying to extract certain data from a string which is like this:

```
2833ae7~2be;2833ae8~2272
```

what i want to do is first split it by the colon, then each record, find if it contains `2be` then split the records which contains it by `~2be`, and give me just the value before `~2be`

I did some essays, and this code kind of does it, but the problem is that it don't gives to me the full output:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<string> split(string str,string sep){
    char* cstr=const_cast<char*>(str.c_str());
    char* current;
    vector<string> arr;
    current=strtok(cstr,sep.c_str());
    while(current!=NULL){
        arr.push_back(current);
        current=strtok(NULL,sep.c_str());
    }
    return arr;
}

int main(){
string items = "2833ae7~2be;2833ae8~2272";
vector<string> food = split(items, ";");
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < food.size(); i++)
{
    if(food[i].find("2be") != string::npos)
    {
        vector<string> arr = split(food[i],"~2be");


        cout << "Output ("<< i << ") = " << arr[0] << endl;

        }// end if

}// end for

    return 0;
}// end main
```

The output i get is:

```
Output <0> = 833a
```

When it should be:

```
Output <0> = 2833ae7
```

What im doing wrong?

Comment: The first problem is that you use C string functions on your `std::string` objects. The `c` in `c_str` stands for *constant*. The data should not be modified. From [this `c_str` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str): "Writing to the character array accessed through c_str() is undefined behavior." And the `strtok` function *writes* to the string. That you have to do a `const_cast` should be an indicator that you do something you should not be doing.

Comment: You are using `strtok` incorrectly. The second argument to the function is a string that contains the set of delimiters which will be used as a token. When you pass `"~2be"` to the function, it tries find any of those characters in first argument. When the first argument is `"2833ae7"`, it will break at the first `2` and will return an empty string.

Comment: `current=strtok(cstr,sep.c_str())` -- Undefined behavior.  The `strtok` mutates the data passed to it, and `cstr` points to a `const char *`.

Comment: As an alternative: `std::vector<char> cstr(str.begin(), str.end()); cstr.push_back(0);` and then `strtok(cstr.data(), sep.c_str())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned in the comments, modifying the character array you get from `std::string::c_str()` is undefined behavior. `strtok()` modifies its parameter to mark the tokens, so you can't use it here.

Splitting an `std::string` by a single-char delimiter is not hard. One way you could do it is like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &input, std::string::value_type delim)
{
    std::stringstream ss(input);
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::string token;
    while (std::getline(ss, token, delim))
    {
        tokens.push_back(token);
    }

    return tokens;
}
```

You can then split your string like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens = split("2833ae7~2be;2833ae8~2272", ';');
```

This will give you a vector containing two elements: "2833ae7~2be" and "2833ae8~2272".

Now for the second part you can't use the same `split()` method because it only works for single-char delimiters. But you could do something like this instead:

```
for (std::size_t index = 0; index < tokens.size(); ++index)
{
    if (tokens[index].find("2be") != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::string::size_type pos = tokens[index].find("~2be");

        std::cout << "Output (" << index << ") = " << tokens[index].substr(0, pos) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Using the same idea you could also try to rewrite the `split()` method to make it work for string delimiters, not just single-char ones like my version.